# How to show GIF image in ProgressDialog box (Android)?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-studio, progressdialog

I have created a custom dialog in which I am using progressDrawable but I am not able to show my GIF image in my ProgressDialog.

In my mainActivity I am just calling the ProgessDialog and using the `show` and `hide` methods.

**Style for dialog:**

```
<style name="CustomDialog" parent="@android:style/Theme.Dialog">
   <item name="android:progressDrawable">@drawable/loading</item>
   <item name="android:background">@android:color/transparent</item> 
   <item name="android:windowBackground">@android:color/transparent</item> 
</style>
```

Comment: Could you share your code ?

Comment: The code snippet is mentioned above